# Precompact set of probability densities

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, compactness

I was confronted with the following problem:

I look at probability densities on $[0,1]$ which are Lipschitz and have a Lipschitz constant smaller than some fixed $L$. Now I would like to show that this set (lets call it $U_L$) is pre-compact in $\mathcal{L}_1$.

I'm not a master of functional analysis, so any idea how to possibly handle this would help me.

Thanks a lot,

DaFischaaa

Comment: That condition gives you equicontinuity more or less immediately. Can you establish uniform boundedness in order to use Arzela-Ascoli?

Comment: Sure, uniform boundedness can be shown since the $\mathcal{L}_1$ integral is bounded and we have a maximal slope. But Arzela Ascoli only gives precompactness in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ and not in $\mathcal{L}_1$, am i wrong?

Comment: Convergence in $C [0,1] $ implies convergence in $L^1$.

Comment: Sure, now I get it. Thank you very much!

Comment: There is actually a catch still, since you wanted to establish *pre*compactness. Precompactness here means the $L^1$ closure of your set should be compact in $L^1$. We showed that the $C[0,1]$ closure of your set is compact in $L^1$. Can you fix this detail? (It is a fairly straightforward fix once you expand out definitions into sequences etc.)